# partial differential equation (PDE)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I can't solve this partial differential equation. Can someone help me?
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\right) ^{2}+\left( \frac{%
  \partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}\right) ^{2}+\frac{2x}{t}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{%
  \partial t}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}=1, 
\end{equation}

Comment: On which domain?

Comment: Hint: Try a similarity solution of the form $f(x,t) \;=\; t\, u(z)$, where $z = x/t$.